# How to retrieve file from Laravel storage subfolder?

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-storage

I'm trying to retrieve a file from this path in a laravel project:

```
/storage/app/public/blog/3.jpg
```

These approaches produce following errors:

1.

```
$image = Storage::disk('public')->get('/storage/blog/3.jpg');
```

->

```
local.ERROR: File not found at path: storage/blog/3.jpg {"userId":16,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Filesystem\\FileNotFoundException(code: 0): File not found at path: storage/blog/3.jpg at /Users/artur/PhpstormProjects/safa-ameedee.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php:171)
[stacktrace]
```

2. 

```
$image = Storage::disk('public')->get('/storage/app/public/blog/3.jpg');
$image = Storage::get('/storage/app/public/blog/3.jpg');
```

->

```
local.ERROR: File not found at path: storage/app/public/blog/3.jpg {"userId":16,"exception":"[object]
```

The weird thing is that I store the files in the storage like so:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('/blog/' . $request->path, $image);
```

So should they not be retrievable in the same way?

Comment: "_So should they not be retrievable in the same way?_" I don't see any code that retrieves the file using the same path, you always add `/storage`.  `Storage::disk('public')->get('/blog/3.jpg');` would be "the same way"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL/DR**

```php
Storage::disk('public')->get('block/3.jpg');
```

**Explanation**

The problem is you're putting `storage` in the path for some reason. It's not necessary and is leading to the wrong path being built.

Take a look at the default filesystems config:

```php
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'throw' => false,
    ],
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'throw' => false,
    ],
```

The `root` is what is useful to see here. `storage_path()` returns the full path to the storage folder. So something like `storage_path('folder_1')` -> `/home/user/project/storage/folder_1`.

The `local` disk is the default, so just doing `Storage::get()` will use it automatically.

You're using the `public` disk, so the actual location of these files is `storage/public` (symlinked into `public/storage`). This means doing `Storage::disk('public')` already begins at `/home/user/project/storage/app/public`. Adding `storage` again makes the path incorrect.

Using `path` may help with future debugging. Storage::disk('public')->path('block/3.jpg') will output the full path, and you can see where it's going wrong. For your code given it would probably show something like `/home/user/project/storage/app/public/storage/app/public`.